# Serialize a mapi message in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, mapi

What I am trying to do is to convert a mapimessage object (LPMESSAGE) into a transferable format let's say to serialize it into bytes ( I prefer this approach), or to xml format. What is the best practice in this case? And how to do it? Is there a library to do so? 
NOTE: I can convert lpmessage into mime and back, but I noticed it loses much of its properties when I use the iconversionsession.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to these classes' internals (and I belive you do), I would advise you to go through this FAQ on serialization: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization. There's everything you would want to know on this topic. (hint: if you don't then you can always derive from them and extend their interface with additional, serialization method.)

If you are not interested in implementing your own solution, you could try 3rd party, like boost serialization lib: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Thank you Piotr for your input, i am looking for a ready solution. does the boost library serialize mapi objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the IMessage to a .MSG file.  While not a perfect process, most properties are preserved, most of the time, and Outlook can open these serialized messages so they're easier to use (and verify).  Search for code samples for OpenIMsgOnIStg.

If you don't want to use MSG as your serialization format, then you'll have to roll your own.  IMAPIProp objects are just property bags with numeric ID's, but all of the different types of property values will have to be persisted differently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am already doing this way, but i do not want to do IO operation into files, is there a way to use OpenIMsgOnIStg without actually persisting the msg file?

Comment: Yes-- use CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal and StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes instead of StgCreateDocfile.